# Can not switch between between profiles while deploying in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, ebcli

I am building two websites using two different AWS Accounts in my Windows 64-bit PC.
I have deployed a website successfully from my first account. Now when I go to deploy from the second account, the application gets created in the first account.

## .aws/config

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id =  1st-user-access-key-id
aws_secret_access_key = 1st-user-secret-access-key
region = us-west-2
output = json


[profile user1]
aws_access_key_id = 2nd-user-access-key-id
aws_secret_access_key = 2nd-user-secret-access-key
region = us-west-2
output = json
```

I have deployed my website from the user **eb-cli**.
Now even after using the code `setx AMAZON_PROFILE user1` if I try to create an application in my **user1** account, it gets deployed in the **eb-cli** user's account.

How do I switch between accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the eb-cli documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-profile) you need to specify an `AWS_EB_PROFILE` environment variable, or use the `--profile` command line option.

I'm not aware of anything that uses `AMAZON_PROFILE`. Most AWS tools like the AWS CLI and the AWS SDKs use `AWS_PROFILE`.